# Drawing ellipse with consecutive vertices

Tags: python, algorithm, draw, ellipse

I ran into a problem with drawing an ellipse. I want to have consecutive vertices of ellipse for my software to draw. I tried to do, but it didn't works. I searched Google thousand times but the results were neither simple enough nor relevant to my target. I also inplemented this code in Python but the results look crazy:

```
import math

a1 = []
a2 = []
a3 = []
a4 = []

def ellipse(a, c):
    if a < c: print("Error!"); return -1
    x = -(a**2)
    while x <= 0.0:
        if x > 0.0: x = 0.0
        y = (a**2 - c**2) * math.sqrt(1 - (-x / a**2))
        if x != -(a**2):
            a2.append([-x, y])
            a4.append([x, -y])
        if x != 0.0:
            a1.append([x, y])
            a3.append([-x, -y])
        x += a**2 / 40.0
    return 0

ellipse(2.0, 0.5)
a2.reverse()
a4.reverse()

aa = a1 + a2 + a3 + a4

print(aa)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WWKu.png

Can anyone help? Also leave a code snippet for me.

Comment: "it didn't work" is not very informative. Please describe the problem.

Comment: I want to draw ellipse. This code is for generating consecutive vertices for drawing.

Comment: Why not just use the `(a*cos(t),b*sin(t))` parameterization? Your code seems needlessly convoluted, with 4 separate lists which are mutated as a side effect to a function call.